# How to search within a class from a menu or add to a class from menu-python

Tags: python, class

I am creating a phone book with python and was stumped on how to search through the class for a specific contact or how to search for a specific entry in the class.

This is what I have so far:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        person.first = first_name
        person_last = last_name
        person_number = phone_number 
class friend:
    def __init__(self, email, birth_date):
        email = johnny.seagraves8219
        birth_date = 8/13/1993
        super(friend, self)._init_
ans = True
while ans:
    print("""
    1. Add a contact
    2. Look up contact by name

    Press enter to quit
    """)
    ans = input("What would you like to do?")
    if ans == "1":

    elif ans == "2":
       look_up = input("Who would you like to look up?")
```

Answer (score 0):

The class will not have entries that you can search through as far as I know. The class is basically just a constructor which is used to create an instance of a, in this case, person in the phone book. You could use an array to hold the instances and then search the array.

```
for i in arrayName:
    if(arrayName[i].first == look_up):
         # do something
```

To create an instance simply call the constructor:

```
firstPerson = person("Mike", "Ryans", "1800838699")
arrayName.append(firstPerson)
```

My knowledge of python is fairly limited but this is what I *think* should work.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, Flexicon is correct: your person/friend class is just a single entity that holds only a single persons information. To be able to search for people, you'll either need to make an array (list) of person objects, a map (dictionary) mapping a name or nickname to the object (so `{'Timmie': <my_timidger_object>}`, or you can wrap one of these approaches in a `AddressBook` class that contains additional methods that one of those basic data structures cannot do for you.

Some other important problems: your friend class does not extend the person, the constructor for a class has two underscores, like `__init__`; as well, you should add default values for email and birth_date in the `person` class, or trying to access these later will cause an error; your attribute need `self` before them or they will not be treated as attribute for the object

Here is Object Orientated (using a list to hold the people) way to do it, though it might be overkill for something this simple:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        self.person.first = first_name
        self.person_last = last_name
        self.person_number = phone_number
        self.email = None #Notice the placeholders?
        self.birth_date   #Not having this information should not be exceptional

class friend(person): #Here, friend extends person
    def __init__(self, email, birth_date):
        self.email = email
        self.birth_date = birth_date
        super(friend, self).__init__()

class AddressBook:
    def __init__(self, people = None):
        if people:
             self.entries = list(people)
        else:
             self.entries = []

    #This is merely an example method, a better way would be to use some relational method like SQL to put in a query to find specific information about the person, but that is beyond the scope of this answer
    def find_num(self, first_name, last_name):
        for person in self.entries:
             if (person.last_name, person.first_name) == (last_name, first_name):
                 return person
        return None
```

Comment: Wow thanks for clearing that up for me I was pretty stumped on this.

Comment: @user3106067 If you want to accept my answer, just hit the green check underneath the score for my answer :)